# Pronunciation of "and it is"?

Tags: pronunciation

Can you please tell me how "and it is" sounds when you say it quickly? Would it be like [andi iz]?

Comment: It depends on the type of English being spoken. I would say _'n it is_, but some people use a 'glottal stop' (a kind of click in the throat) to replace 't' in the middle of a word or phrase - _i' is_. It's unlikely that anyone would sound the 'd' in casual speech.

Comment: Thank you Kate. I'm listening to sentences in a book using Audible, and it is difficult to catch that part. But indeed, it somewhat sounds like [an itiz].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronunciation kind of goes like this: "an its", the "d" part is silent if you speak a little fast but not silent if you are stressing it or speaking slowly.

Comment: Yes, I felt like I heard the sound of d, but it was not likely. Many thanks!

Comment: If it's in the middle of a sentence, it's likely to be "and it's" anyway. If it's at the end of a sentence, as in "I told you that was the answer and it is!" then "is" would be emphasised, and not reduced at all.

Comment: @ColinFine - Yes, of course - I was thinking of it as a separate mini-sentence, but of course in a longer sentence one would say _it's_.

Comment: Yes in my case that part is followed by a verb with "ing",  making a new sentence from it. Thank you Kate.